# How to get user photos from Picasa and Flicker?

Tags: android, flickr, photos, picasa

I am working on a project in which i need to integrate the `picasa` and `Flicker` to get the photos to my app.

`Picasa`

I searched for it got some links http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html but it doesn't work for me . there is no android tutorial in that link, please help me regarding this issue. it would be grate if any body help me with the sample project.

`flicker`

In this by passing user id, created from the Flickr website, able to get the images from a particular account. But i don't know how to get User Id by passing username and password from my app.

**Edit :** I would really appreciate any WORKING example, which tells me how to connect to the Picasa from Android in a step-by-step way. I have browsed Internet and downloading tons of git repositories with examples for three days always finding Deprecated, not working or not Android examples, or even broken links.

Comment: Why -ve marking, anybody explain the reason. whats the wrong in my Question. i was did my work about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked with `flickr on android` before and reccomend using the `JSON api.`
**List of a users photosets**

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=**API 
KEY**8&user_id=**USER ID**@N07&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

**List of photos in a users photoset**

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=**API
KEY**8&photoset_id=**PHOTOSET ID**&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

**List of a users public photos**

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=**API 
KEY**&user_id=**USER ID**@N07&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

R.E `Picasa` I would recommend looking at their API Docs [Picasa Developers](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the API of Flickr/Picasa to fetch certain details about the user.
You will have to register to the service provider and get an API KEY to use its services.

**Flicker**
[Flickr Android API](http://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/)

**PicasaWeb**
[Picasa Web Data Albums API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/)

You should read the manuals, code examples and get around some opensource projects to get a good grip of the API capabilities and opportunities.

Comment: i read documentation what you provided in the above link but i did't get any proper solution, can u provide any example if you have.or tutorial link's